# Redirect internally to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all the `/docs/*` requests to `/docs/` so that index.php can handle it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/docs/[a-z]+
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^docs/(.*)$ /docs/ [L,QSA]
```

But the above .htaccess configuration throws the following error.

**Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.**

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/docs/[a-z]+
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^docs/(.*)$ /docs/index.php/$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I don't wish to redirect to another page. I have a single page. index.php. I want to redirect all my requests internally to the same page. so `/docs/$1` is not what I need.

Comment: Yes, it's there. And It should handle all the files requests in /docs/

Comment: check the updated answer.now index.php will handle all requests

Comment: keep the index.php file in outside docs..and check this `RewriteRule ^docs/(.*)$ index.php/$0 [L,QSA] `